# Custom Font in IOS Not Reflected On Device

Tags: ios, iphone, fonts, swift2

i followed this [tutorial](https://grokswift.com/custom-fonts/) and the custom font was shown on my storyboard but when i executed my app (on simulator or device) the font is not reflected. can anyone help.
this is what i did:

```
1- downloaded a .ttf file and copied it to my project
2- added "Fonts Provided By Application" in info.plist and added a row having the name of my custom font.
3- opened storyboard and selected the UILabel i want to have a custom font for, and selected the font as custom then selected my font. the font was shown on the storyboard correctly.
```

am i missing something?

Comment: Make sure the font file is included in your target: click on it, then go the the File Inspector (first tab in the panel on the right of the window) and check that there's a checkmark next to your target in the "Target Membership" section.

Comment: Also check that you listed the file name, and not the font name, in your Info.plist.

Comment: What if you do NSLog(@"%@", [UIFont familyNames]);? Is your font family name displayed there in the list?

Comment: the checkmark was not selected so i selected it. this is probably because i am using multiple languages. and when printing the NSLog i don't see the font name

Comment: once you selected the checkmark do Clean and then run the app again and see if it prints familyName (not font name!) now

Comment: @rashad.z : Can you please specify which font you want to use. The one that is available under the "Family Name" when you are selecting Custom font. Or is it any different?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thank you @Andrey Chernuka and @jcaron. I solved the problem by setting the target membership to my project and then exiting the project (cleaning did not work for some reason) and reopening the project and everything was set. the font name was appearing when i printed   `print (UIFont.familyNames())`

Answer (score 1):

Have you added .ttf folder to supporting files only. 
Then Edit info.Plist like this

Fonts provided by Application take as array

Item 0 as Heiti SC.ttf

now you can set `label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Heiti SC" size:15];`

Then you also need to add ttf file to copy bundle resources in target build phases.

Comment: "Then you also need to add ttf file to copy bundle resources in target build phases." --> This did the trick for me !!

Answer (score 1):

You just follow below steps.

Step 1 - downloaded a .ttf file and copied it to my project
Step 2 - added "Fonts Provided By Application" in info.plist and added a row having the name of my custom font.

[image]

Step 3 -  Display added fonts exist into project or not. copy past into `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

```
NSLog(@"Available fonts: %@", [UIFont familyNames]);
NSArray *familyNames = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[UIFont familyNames]];
    NSArray *fontNames;
    NSInteger indFamily, indFont;
    for (indFamily=0; indFamily<[familyNames count]; ++indFamily)
    {
        NSLog(@"Family name: %@", [familyNames objectAtIndex:indFamily]);
        fontNames = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:
                     [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:
                      [familyNames objectAtIndex:indFamily]]];
        for (indFont=0; indFont<[fontNames count]; ++indFont)
        {
            NSLog(@"    Font name: %@", [fontNames objectAtIndex:indFont]);
        }

    }
```

Step 4 - find the name of your font and same name check into story board.

It's definitely works.