# Custom font issue in iOS 9?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

I am using custom font in iOS.For using custom font i have followed below steps.

- .Add **.ttf** in project.
- Add fontname under **plist** file
- Print font name using below code

  ```
  for (NSString *fontFamilyName in [UIFont familyNames]) {
  for (NSString *fontName in [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:fontFamilyName]) {
      NSLog(@"Family: %@    Font: %@", fontFamilyName, fontName);
  }
  ```

  }

**Font name is**

```
self.label_co.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Digital-7Mono" size:20];
```

I am able to see font name in font name list in storyboard.I am able to use font on storyboard on interface builder but when i run the app custom font is not shown

Comment: refer this http://stackoverflow.com/a/34154951/5362916

Comment: Remove fontname from plist. If you use fonts in xibs and storyboards, they are automatically added into plist during complication.

Comment: Check the font file is exist in Build Phases->Copy Bundle Resources ?

Comment: May I show your code ? Whats is font name ?

Comment: What is your font file name ? and what you added in .plist ?

Answer (score 1):

Some times font is not copy in "Copy Bundle Resources" so please do and may be same issue happen in your case.
so `Tap on you project target->Build Phases->Copy Bundle Resources` and see font file exist or not, if font file not exist add the font to bundle resources using `+` button sign at bottom, press it and add font file to resources. Thats it now check it you can got results :)

OR

As per your Edited answer you used Digital-7 mono font so you have to write it like this.

```
self.label_co.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Digital-7" size:20];
```

instead of

```
self.label_co.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Digital-7Mono" size:20];
```

This will definitely worked.

Answer (score 0):

Click your font in the xcode project and in the right side property window, you'll see an option like Target membership. Make sure whether it is checked for your app. Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the Mono from Digital-7Mono in Bundle and info.plist.give everywhere as Digital-7.it was worked me.

```
self.label_co.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Digital-7" size:20];
```

Comment: Then what is in my answer ? Why are you post same answer ?

Comment: @DipenChudasama  see,I didnot read your answer fully.I got same problem 2 days before so,i posted my answer.

Comment: i think i might not added in CopyBundle resourses.delete .ttf from bundle and re add the .ttf file .(You must and should give the tick mark for add to targets otherwise it will not work)

Comment: Then it will work Boss,Please check the spell mistakes from your sides

Comment: Check from story board if .ttf added successfully then you can directly set from storyboard By selecting Digital-7 from fonts for label

Comment: In storyboard it is showing me correct font but when i set through code then it does not work

Comment: Why your using this code

 (NSString *fontFamilyName in [UIFont familyNames]) {
for (NSString *fontName in [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:fontFamilyName]) {
    NSLog(@"Family: %@    Font: %@", fontFamilyName, fontName);
}

Answer (score 0):

Making UITextview "selectable" from storyboard will work. But text is selectable. Another way to do this is Attributed.