# Custom font in Swift 5 not working in Xcode 10

Tags: ios, swift, uifont

I am trying to add Custom Fonts in Xcode 10 & I keep getting this error:

> Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

- I have included the fonts in my Info.plist
- I have checked my "Copy Bundle Resources" & It is there.

I still get this error.

This my code below:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    let paragraph = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    paragraph.alignment = .center

    let attributedString = NSAttributedString(string: message, attributes:
        [.paragraphStyle: paragraph, NSAttributedString.Key.font : UIFont (name: "Lato-Regular", size: 14)!]) // Throws error here

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)
    alert.setValue(attributedString, forKey: "attributedMessage")

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Back", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
    self.present(alert, animated: true)
}
```

Throws Error on this line

```
UIFont (name: "Lato-Regular", size: 14)!
```

Xcode cannot find font, but I can also use the font on the Storyboard UI. So how come?

Comment: What is the name of your font in Story board UI? Check spelling

Comment: Try this: `UIFont(name: "Lato", size: 14)!`

Comment: @BhavinRamani thanks but getting same error

Comment: @karthikeyan my font has the correct name, I have used this in another old project & it works fine.

Comment: Check your font available or not through code and make sure your font file should checked in targets

Comment: @karthikeyan please what do you mean by "checked in targets"?

Comment: Like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/KlchK.png

Comment: you refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27006772/custom-font-not-working-programmatically-in-swift

Comment: @karthikeyan Yes, my target is set.

Comment: this may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48268683/1042817

Answer (score 0):

`UIFont.familyNames` will give you a list of all available font families. `UIFont.fontNames(forFamilyName:)` will give you all font names. Use that to find out the correct name of your font.

```
let families = UIFont.familyNames
let allFonts = families.flatMap { UIFont.fontNames(forFamilyName:$0) }
let latoFonts = allFonts.filter { $0.contains("Lato") }
print(latoFonts)
```