# Custom font importation

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, fonts, xcode9

I'm having trouble adding a custom front on my IOS project on Xcode 9...

I tried everything proposed on this toppic: [Xcode 9 custom fonts not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46303443/xcode-9-custom-fonts-not-working)
but nothing worked out.

On my project, I got my `FugazOne-Regular.ttf` file, his target membership is set to my app. My `Info.plist` has `Front provided by application` and Item 0 is set to `FugazOne-Regular.ttf`. `FugazOne-Regular.ttf` is also in Copy bundle resources, in Build phases.

If I try to print every font name with something like this:

`for family in UIFont.familyNames.sorted() {
    let names = UIFont.fontNames(forFamilyName: family)
    print("Family: \(family) Font names: \(names)")
}`

I can see all the defaults fonts but no FugazOne-Regular or anything similar,

I tried deleting the font, cleaning the project but nothing changed...

(it is my first time posting here so tell me if I am doing anything wrong)

UPDATE: I thing this might be an Xcode bug, I'm using Xcode 9.4.1 but un macOS Mojave.

Comment: Did you check copy items if needed when dragging the font to the project?

Comment: Yeah, I tried to change options several times when dragging the files in, nothing changed I still can't print the font.

Answer (score 0):

Repeat the following steps:

1. Import the font to the project by dragging it to Xcode and check `Copy items if needed` and your desired targets

[image: Import to Xcode]

2. Add into your .plist file (careful with spelling)

[image]

3. Drag the imported font **from the project inside Xcode, NOT from Finder** into Build Phases > Copy Bundle Resources

[image: Copy Bundle Resources]

Comment: Thats how I tried multiple times, but I think this must be a bug in Xcode (my Xcode version is 9.4.1, but I use macOS Mojave beta)

Comment: Indeed! With the new Xcode and everything up-to-date, it works perfectly